# Curly braces inside array destructuring in return from a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can´t understand how the curly braces work (or what are they supposed to do) in the return of this custom hook. I know it´s destructuring, I just don´t understand the need for them. Could anyone explain?

```
const useHackerNewsApi = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({ hits: [] });
  const [url, setUrl] = useState(
    'https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=redux',
  );
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      setIsError(false);
      setIsLoading(true);
      try {
        const result = await axios(url);
        setData(result.data);
      } catch (error) {
        setIsError(true);
      }
      setIsLoading(false);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [url]);
  return [{ data, isLoading, isError }, setUrl];
}
```

Comment: That's not destructuring that's just returning an array and at the first element combining `data`, `isLoading` and `isError` into a single object

Comment: But aren´t the properties inside the object destructured? Or do they get turned into {data: data}, etc?

Comment: They do get turned into `{ data: data }` that's ES6 object properties shorthand notation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're basically returning an array that contains an Object at the 0th index and `setUrl` method at the second index.

The return value would be implicitly converted into:

```
[{
  data: data,
  isLoading: isLoading,
  isError: isError
}, setUrl]
```

That's why you'd be able to use it like this in your Component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useHackerNewsApi } from "./useHackerNewsAPI";

export default ({ name }) => {
  const [{ data, isLoading, isError }, setUrl] = useHackerNewsApi();
  return <h1>
    <pre> Data - { JSON.stringify(data) }</pre>
    <pre> isLoading - { isLoading }</pre>
    <pre> isError - { isError }</pre>
  </h1>;
};
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hacker-rank-custom-data-hook?file=Hello.js) for your ref.